# Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8181: Connection refused

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, curl

I am having a problem sending http requests to a Laravel API via a NodeJS server on my local machine.

I run my Laravel app on port 8181:

```
$ php artisan serve --port=8181
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8181/
```

But when I attempt to send requests to this endpoint via a [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) server I get the below response:

```
$ npm run server-dev
> stryve@0.3.0-alpha server-dev F:\Code\stryve
> SET PROD_ENV=0 & node src/server.js


Listening on *:3333

User connected and ready.
A user has connected to the server.
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8181]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8181 }
{ errorCode: 0,
  errorMessage: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8181' }
```

When attempting to hit `localhost` with a curl request, I get a successful response:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8181/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    46    0    46    0     0    978      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   978{"code":200,"status":"OK","message":"success"}
```

but if I switch out `localhost` for `127.0.0.1` it fails:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8181
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8181: Connection refused
```

In my node app, my base url is set to use `localhost`:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8181/api';
```

However, it seems that node translates this to `127.0.0.1`. Is there a way to force node to use `localhost`?

**EDIT:**

I also tried adding the below to my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

I'm using Windows 10 (64-bit) with [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) to run all commands.

**EDIT #2:**

Have disabled the Windows firewall but am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Check that the port is open through a router if applicable. Also check that the firewall isn't blocking it. I suspect you'll have to create a rule in your firewall.

Comment: Just disabled windows firewall and tested but still fails. Not sure how to check if the port is open. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you ping 127.0.0.1 - do you get response?

Comment: And I assume you restarted the server that's opening the port so that it can acknowledge the host file changes. Just the server not necessarily the OS. A complete restart should be tried too, but I assume you have done that as well.

Comment: Run this in command prompt and see if port is listed `netstat -a -n`

Comment: Since you can connect via localhost it seems the port is open. I feel like your host file hasn't been acknowledged yet.

Comment: The ping to 127.0.0.1 resolves, though I don't see port `8181` listed when I run `netstat -a -n`. I have to go to work now but will look into this when I get home. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Replace localhost or 127.0.0.1 in the code to 0.0.0.0 for the hostname configuration of Laravel. That should force it to listen on all IP addresses. This might be helpful http://laravel.io/forum/05-18-2014-how-to-set-the-current-environment